# Server unresponsive after successful OpenSSL connection

Tags: ssl, telnet, openssl

I'm testing server connections using OpenSSL, with varying results

- Server A: connection is successful, as are user login and the other commands I expected to work
- Server B: connection is successful, but the server is unresponsive when I try to submit a command. I don't get an error, or even a disconnection – just a blank line from where I hit Enter or ^M

My hunch is that Server B's configuration requires a different character encoding or something and it's simply not recognizing my Enter keystroke, but I've looked to no avail... any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean OpenSSH?

Comment: I connect using `openssl s_client -connect server.com:port`, in lieu of telnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my initial suspicion was correct... the server simply wasn't accepting my Enter command. Adding the `-crlf`  flag took care of it:

`openssl s_client -connect server:port -crlf`

From what I've read, this forces the s_client tool to send a `CR/LF` when you hit enter, which is needed for a Windows-based server to read. It's likely, then, that Server A worked because it was a *NIX server and Server B is a Windows server.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Looks like there's a 24-hour delay between when you answer your own question and when you can accept it, though. Guess I'll stop back later.

Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming like @UtahJarhead that you mean OpenSSH.

I don't know much about encodings, but I would be surprised to learn that things like space, enter, null etc - low-end ASCII stuff - differed.

1. **Check the shell of Server B's user**. Can you get access to that machine somehow and `su` to that user? Does the same problem occur?
2. **Check the sshd config**. Are there any fishy options like `ChrootDirectory`, `ForceCommand`, etc? Diff the sshd configs from both servers and see what looks suspect
3. **Debug**. Connect to Server B like `ssh -vvv user@serverb` and look for sus output. My shell allocation looks like:

   ```
   debug2: channel 1: request shell confirm 1
   debug2: callback done
   debug2: channel 1: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
   debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
   debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 1
   debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 2097152
   debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
   debug2: shell request accepted on channel 1
   ```

   These are the last lines of debug output for me.

Failing any of that - what obvious stuff differs between these machines?

Comment: I don't have SSH access to server B – I'm connecting as a client using `openssl s_client -connect` in lieu of telnet because the server requires a secure connection.

Comment: Which SSH can provide.